# Unable to access RabbitMQ management port through Nginx reverse proxy on subdirectory URL

Tags: nginx, ssl, proxy, rabbitmq, reverse-proxy

I have an Nginx server with multiple location blocks, including one for proxying requests to RabbitMQ management port. The server is set up to listen on port 443 with SSL, and it is configured with a server block for redirecting HTTP requests to HTTPS.

Here's an excerpt from my Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    # certbot needs either port 80 or 443 open to connect
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/html/;
    }

    location /rabbitmq/{
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:15672";
    }

    location /{
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "https://127.0.0.1:9001";
    }

    location /baristadj{
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass "http://baristadjdev.example.com";
    }

    #this is where socket io will be handling the request
    location /rest/messages{
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/messages";
    }
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    error_page 500 502 /etc/nginx/www/500.html;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

When I try to access example.com/rabbitmq, it says "Not Found". However, I am able to access the web application on example.com. Additionally, when I try accessing example.com:15672 explicitly, I am able to access the RabbitMQ management port over HTTP.

For testing purposes, I changed the location /rabbitmq/ mapping to root mapping '/' and deleted the existing root mapping. In that case, Nginx successfully proxied the request to the RabbitMQ management port, and I was able to access it over HTTPS.

How can I configure my Nginx server to properly proxy requests to the RabbitMQ management port when using the /rabbitmq/ mapping?

Comment: can you try accessing example,com/rabbitmq*/* ?
there is some more information [here](https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/3RJVx4CryxI) as to why that might work, combined with a strong recommandation to test in incognito mode to avoid browser caching issues.

Comment: @Olivier
Thank you so much Oliver. The link provided by you helped me. It is working now. Cheers